# Content Search WebPart Query

Tags: web-part, office-365, content-query-web-part

I am trying to get the content search webpart to display a list of subsites but it only shows me the site I am on (Topsite)

Here is my query:

Path:"https://sitename.sharepoint.com/projects "  contentclass:STS_Web  SiteTitle <> projects

Can anyone please advise?

Thanks!

Alan

Answer (score 1):

You could either try with a wildcard

```
Path:"https://sitename.sharepoint.com/projects/*" contentclass:STS_Web SiteTitle <> projects
```

Or got with the URL Depth property:

```
Path:"https://sitename.sharepoint.com/projects " contentclass:STS_Web SiteTitle <> projects UrlDepth=1
```

And to make it a little bit smoother, go with

```
Path:{Site.URL} UrlDepth=1 contentclass:STS_Web
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the query should have been:
Path:"https://sitename.sharepoint.com/projects "  contentclass:STS_Web  Site<>{Site.URL}

Also remember to give SHarePoint a chance to index your new sites.